# Restore a particular stored procedure from .bkp file

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.bkp` file and I deleted a stored procedure unknowingly in SQL Server. Can anyone help to restore  a particular stored procedure from the backup file instead of loading the whole backup?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but interested to see if anyone has any ideas!

Comment: what type of backup is that ?

Comment: The standard SQL Server backups (usually `.bak` files) is an all-or-nothing thing - you cannot restore single objects from that backup - you can only restore the whole database. But things like stored procedures should be stored inside `.sql` source files and be handled by **source control** - so you should be able to restore / re-create a stored procedure at any time, from your stored source code, anyway...